# moving map in mapview from one location to another in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

i have a situation in  my app where i should move my map from one location to another location....i am quite new to android..and i found out how to draw a line in between two locations..

```
public class Mapview extends MapActivity implements LocationListener{
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p,p1,p2;
LocationManager lm;
String provider;
 class Mapoverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
 {

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        Point screenpoints=new Point();     
        Point screenpoints1=new Point();
        Point screenpoints2=new Point();
         Paint paint;
         paint = new Paint();
         paint.setColor(Color.RED);
         paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
         paint.setAlpha(120);
         Paint paint1;
         paint1 = new Paint();
         paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
         paint1.setStyle(Style.FILL);
         paint1.setStrokeWidth(2);
         paint1.setAlpha(120);
        if(p != null)
        {
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenpoints);
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p1, screenpoints1);
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p2, screenpoints2);
//              Bitmap map=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),      R.drawable.pushpin1);
//               canvas.drawBitmap(map, screenpoints.x, screenpoints.y-53, null);
             canvas.drawLine(screenpoints.x,screenpoints.y,screenpoints1.x,screenpoints1.y, paint);
             canvas.drawLine(screenpoints.x,screenpoints.y,screenpoints2.x,screenpoints2.y, paint);
        }

        return true;

    }

 }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
    MapView map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     mc=map.getController();
     String[] coordinates={"51.4750766129036", "-3.15672342166522"};
     double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
     double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

     p=new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6), (int)(lng*1E6));
     String[] coordinates1={"17.453117" , "78.467586" };
     double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates1[0]);
     double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(coordinates1[1]);

     p2=new GeoPoint((int)(lat1*1E6), (int)(lng1*1E6));
      p1 = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);

//        p = new GeoPoint(19241000,-99121000);
     lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
     criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
     criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
     criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
     criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
     criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
     provider=lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


     Location loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
     List<String>  lists=lm.getAllProviders();
//       float f=loc.distanceTo(loc);
     if (loc!=null){
         System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(loc); 
     }else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provider " + provider+ loc +  lists+" has not been selected.", 5000).show();
//           this.finish();
     }

//       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p.getLatitudeE6()+p.getLongitudeE6(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     mc.animateTo(p);
     mc.setZoom(1);
     map.invalidate();
     Mapoverlay mapOverlay = new Mapoverlay();
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = map.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

}
```

i am stuck at moving map from one location to another without user activity

for example:when the app initiates location of newyork city is shown then the map should  move to texas ...any help willl be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Try This class just pass **Activity act,GeoPoint src,GeoPoint dest, int color, MapView mMapView**

```
To call this class do this

    new getRoute().DrawPath(this,mGeoPoint,getGeoPoint,Color.RED,mMapView);  





  public class getRoute 
    {
        /*Variable*/
        double mIntentLatitude, mIntentLongitude;
        double mCursorLatitude, mCursorLongitude, mStartLatitude, mStartLongitude, mEndLatitude, MEndLongitude;
        String mJsonData;
        String mEnd_Address, mStart_Address, mName;
        int mLength;
        GeoPoint mGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(220328269, 725588202);
        double mLatitude_End[], mLongitude_End[], mLatitude_Start[], mLongitude_Start[];
        Activity activity;


        public getRoute
        (){

        }   
        boolean error = false;
        public void DrawPath(Activity act,GeoPoint src,GeoPoint dest, int color, MapView mMapView01)
        {
            // connect to map web service
            DrawPathBack draw = new DrawPathBack(act, src, dest, color, mMapView01);
            draw.execute("Draw");
        }
        public class DrawPathBack extends AsyncTask<String, Integer,Void>
        {
            ProgressDialog bar;
            List<Overlay> mListOverlay;
            MapOverlay mapOverlay;
            ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> mItemizedOverlay;

            GeoPoint src,dest;
            int color;
            MapView mMapView;
            CommonMethod mCommonMethod;
            String [] pairs;
            String[] lngLat;



            public DrawPathBack(Activity act,GeoPoint gpsrc,GeoPoint gpdest, int c, MapView mMap)
            {
                activity =act;
                src=gpsrc;
                dest=gpdest;
                color = c;
                mMapView=mMap;
                mListOverlay = mMapView.getOverlays();
                mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(mGeoPoint);
                mListOverlay.add(mapOverlay);
                mMapView.invalidate();

            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
            {



                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 60000);

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                try {

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+ (Double.toString((double)src.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6)) + "," +(Double.toString((double)src.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ) + "&destination=" + (Double.toString((double)dest.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6)) + ","+  (Double.toString((double)dest.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6))+ "&sensor=false"));
                    mIntentLatitude=((double)src.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6);
                    mIntentLongitude=((double)src.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6);

                    //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
                    mJsonData = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
            {
                bar.setMessage("Time Progress "+progress[0]);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
            {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(mJsonData);

                    // grabbing the routes object
                    JSONArray routes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("routes");

                    for (int i = 0; i < routes.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject rout = routes.getJSONObject(i);

                        JSONObject bounds = rout.getJSONObject("bounds");

                        JSONObject northest = bounds.getJSONObject("northeast");

                        mStartLatitude = northest.getDouble("lat");
                        mStartLongitude = northest.getDouble("lng");

                        JSONObject southwest = bounds.getJSONObject("southwest");
                        mEndLatitude = southwest.getDouble("lat");
                        MEndLongitude = southwest.getDouble("lng");
                        System.out.println("get data from jeson" + mCursorLatitude + mCursorLongitude + mEndLatitude
                                + MEndLongitude);

                        // grabbing the routes legs
                        JSONArray legs = rout.getJSONArray("legs");
                        System.out.println("length of legs array     " + legs.length());
                        for (int j = 0; j < legs.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject leg = legs.getJSONObject(j);
                            System.out.println("enter in second array");

                            JSONObject distance = leg.getJSONObject("distance");
                            String mTextDistent = distance.getString("text");
                            System.out.println("distances bitween two point" + mTextDistent);
                            JSONObject duration = leg.getJSONObject("duration");
                            String mTextDurestion = duration.getString("text");

                            mEnd_Address = leg.getString("end_address");

                            mStart_Address = leg.getString("start_address");
                            System.out.println("get data from jeson in second arry"
                                    + mTextDurestion + " " + mEnd_Address + "  " + mStart_Address);

                            JSONArray step = leg.getJSONArray("steps");

                            mLength = step.length();

                            mLatitude_End = new double[mLength];
                            mLongitude_End = new double[mLength];
                            mLatitude_Start = new double[mLength];
                            mLongitude_Start = new double[mLength];

                            for (int k = 0; k < step.length(); k++) {

                                JSONObject st = step.getJSONObject(k);

                                System.out.println("enter in third array");
                                JSONObject end_lo = st.getJSONObject("end_location");

                                JSONObject start_lo = st
                                .getJSONObject("start_location");

                                mLatitude_End[k] = end_lo.getDouble("lat");
                                mLongitude_End[k] = end_lo.getDouble("lng");

                                mLatitude_Start[k] = start_lo.getDouble("lat");
                                mLongitude_Start[k] = start_lo.getDouble("lng");

                            }
                            for (int mDistanse = 0; mDistanse < mLength; mDistanse++) {
                                System.out.println("end location let" + mLatitude_End[mDistanse]);
                                System.out.println("end location long+"
                                        + mLongitude_End[mDistanse]);
                                System.out.println("Start location let"
                                        + mLatitude_Start[mDistanse]);
                                System.out.println("Start location long"
                                        + mLongitude_Start[mDistanse]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

            public MapOverlay(GeoPoint mGeoPoint) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean draw(final Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
                    boolean shadow, long when) {

                Point mpoint = new Point();
                Point mpoint1 = new Point();

                int let[] = new int[mLength];
                int lon[] = new int[mLength];
                int let_end[] = new int[mLength];
                int lon_end[] = new int[mLength];
                GeoPoint newGeoPoint = null;
                GeoPoint newGeoPoint1;
                for (int k = 0; k < mLength; k++) {

                    let[k] = (int) (mLatitude_Start[k] * 1E6);
                    lon[k] = (int) (mLongitude_Start[k] * 1E6);

                    let_end[k] = (int) (mLatitude_End[k] * 1E6);
                    lon_end[k] = (int) (mLongitude_End[k] * 1E6);
                    newGeoPoint1 = new GeoPoint(let_end[k], lon_end[k]);
                    newGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(let[k], lon[k]);
                    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(newGeoPoint, mpoint);
                    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(newGeoPoint1, mpoint1);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();

                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
                    canvas.drawCircle(mpoint.x, mpoint.y, 5, paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    canvas.drawLine(mpoint.x, mpoint.y, mpoint1.x, mpoint1.y, paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(100);
                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                    if(k==mLength-1){
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.green_pin);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,mpoint1.x ,mpoint1.y-30, null);
                    }
                    GeoPoint dumy=new GeoPoint((int)(mIntentLatitude * 1E6), (int)(mIntentLongitude * 1E6));
                    Point dumy1 = new Point();
                    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(dumy, dumy1);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.dest_pin);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,dumy1.x,dumy1.y - 25, null);
                    mapView.getController().animateTo(dumy);
                    mapView.invalidate();
                }
                return false;

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: this was very useful...but in this i can get the route..i want move the map to other location without help of user...

Comment: @aravindvarma : then in on create pass lat,long in "setCenter" it will automatically navigate to your location.

Comment: there are two geopoints...i want the map to navigate from one location to another automatically..if i pass"setCenter" the provided location wiil be appeared directly

Comment: @aravindvarma : then take some timer and after particular time recall the method.

Comment: thnk you...what can i do for the navigation to be slow...so that i can see the map move

Comment: myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     try {} catch (Exception e)
     {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

Comment: @aravindvarma if you don't use user current location then call your navigation point in

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to move map on particular position then get lat or long of that position and just pass in this :

```
MapController mMapController;

mMapController=mMapView.getController();
    mMapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6)));
```

and if you want to draw path between two location then just pass lat and lon in this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ String.valueOf(from_lattitude) +","+ String.valueOf(from_longitude) +"&daddr="+ String.valueOf(dest_lati) +","+ String.valueOf(dest_longi)));
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thnk u for your answer..the intent in your code will have to open browser or google maps in mobile...i want it to happen in the application not using browser or other apps

Comment: @aravindvarma I post another ans for draw path try it.