# how to draw Google Map Route in android

Tags: android, google-maps, http, android-intent

I try to get Map route between two places in android and i refered this Link, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608601/android-google-maps-and-drawing-route)

but its showing error at this two places,

```
HttpClient oHttp = HttpClient.getInterfaces();
        String szXml = oHttp.doGet(szUrl,"");
```

how to solve this

Comment: try this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246084/moving-map-in-mapview-from-one-location-to-another-in-android/13248095#13248095

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps